# organize data on front-end with javascript

Tags: javascript

I can console.log my data on the front-end but I need to do some logic to organize this data and I'm not sure what the best approach is for this type of issue. I need to get a 'count' for how many analyses belong to each project. So below each object has a project_id and an analysis_id. So there must be a way to get to create a count variable for each object that represents how many analyses belong to each project, with javascript. Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. Create an object, for each object you are iterating over check if you have an existing property for that project_id. If not initialize it to 0. Then add 1 to it.

```
var projectCounts = {}, index = 0; length = someData.length;
for ( ; index < length; index++) {
  var projectId = someData[index].project_id;
  if (!projectCounts['Project' + projectId]) {
    projectCounts['Project' + projectId] = 0;
  }
  projectCounts['Project' + projectId]++
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lbohgnxs/

EDIT: So if you want these counts on each object you can just set the counts through each iteration. Because objects are just a reference to a spot in memory each reference will have the final values after the loop is complete.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lbohgnxs/1/

```
var projectCounts = {}, index = 0; length = someData.length;
for ( ; index < length; index++) {
  var projectId = someData[index].project_id;
  if (!projectCounts['Project' + projectId]) {
    projectCounts['Project' + projectId] = 0;
  }
  projectCounts['Project' + projectId]++
  someData[index].counts = projectCounts;
}
```

If you don't like having every count and just want the specific project count you can create a count object and use that reference as well.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lbohgnxs/2/

```
var projectCounts = {}, index = 0; length = someData.length;
for ( ; index < length; index++) {
  var projectId = someData[index].project_id;
  if (!projectCounts['Project' + projectId]) {
    projectCounts['Project' + projectId] = {count: 0};
  }
  projectCounts['Project' + projectId].count++
  someData[index].counts = projectCounts['Project' + projectId];
}
```

Comment: This is a good thought, however it just creates a completely new object. I need to add a 'count' variable to each of the current objects so I can display them in a table.

Comment: Well you could always just set this object on each guy you iterate over and simply by pass by reference in javascript they all will continue to be updated as you iterate over each object. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Lbohgnxs/1/

Comment: If you could update your fiddle that would really help me understand, thanks

Comment: Updated again to remove counts of other projects.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop the array and update an object that maps project IDs to their counts:

```js
// simplified sample data
var analyses = [
  {
    project_id: 1,
    analysis_id: 10
  },
  {
    project_id: 2,
    analysis_id: 11
  },
  {
    project_id: 3,
    analysis_id: 12
  },
  {
    project_id: 3,
    analysis_id: 13
  }
];

var counts = {};

analyses.forEach( function(el) {
    var pid = el.project_id;
  
    counts[pid] = counts[pid] || 0;  // start at 0 if we haven't seen this project before
    ++counts[pid];
});

console.log(counts);    // {1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2
```